# Intellij IDEA. Как настроить компиляцию модулей проекта в различные папки?

Tags: intellij-idea

Использую *IDEA* (*v14 Community Edition*). Мне нужно импортировать проекты из *Eclipse* (несколько штук, подключенных один к другому). Я создал проект (отдельный фолдер на диске) и подключил модули (проекты *Eclipse*).

Теперь при компиляции проекта *IDEA* все файлы `*.class` попадают в дефолтовую папку созданного проекта. Её можно изменить, но это, похоже, сработает все равно для всех модулей. Сборщик проекта настроен на источнк для *class*-файлов в персональных папках каждого модуля.

Как настроить компиляцию проекта *IDEA*, чтобы *class*-файлы каждого модуля попадали в свои персональные папки?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

`File` -> `Project structure (Ctrl + alt + shift + S)` -> `Modules`.
Для каждого модуля выбираешь вкладку `Paths` и выбираешь `Use module compile output path`. И выставляешь путь, в который у тебя должны скомпилироваться классы ( для тестов и исходников)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно я не дал полную информацию.

### Вид получившегося проекта:

### [image: вид проекта в IDEA]

вид в меню настроки структуры:
[image: вид в меню Project structure]
+ к проекту добавлены Сontent Root (src проектов)
пулучается, что вкладка Paths относится ко всему проекту, а персональное редактирование возможно только для Сontent Root. Если добавлять к my_project проекты Eclipse отдельно ("+"слева вверху), тогда пропадут пути к исходникам из  Сontent Root (или нет?). и как в этом случае пойдет компиляция - отдельно для каждого добавленного или все что прописано за 1 проход?
Возможно надо переделать структуру проекта? если да - то как?